# How can I use an angular scope variable inside a repeater

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am just starting with angular. I want to pass an array of objects and a specific property of an object I would like to display inside my iteration. 
I am trying to create a directive that will be used as below:

The **html** code

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
   <pass-object objects="objs" prop="'value'"></pass-object>
</div>
```

The **directive** code:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[])
    .controller('MyCtrl', function ($scope) {
        $scope.objs = [{ value: "hello" },{ value: "world" }];
    })
    .directive('passObject', function() {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            scope: { objects: '=', prop: '@' },
            template: '<span data-ng-repeat="obj in objects">{{obj[prop]}}</span>'
        };
    });
```

This in **NOT** working because the prop value can not be evaluated like this. Because the prop should be compiled before it is used in the repeat.

Outside the repeat I can display the property as string with

```
<span>{{prop}}</span>
```

How can I evaluate the value inside the repeat like {{obj["value"]}}

Answer (score 1):

This is the difference :

prop="value"

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <pass-object prop="value" objects="objs"></pass-object>
</body>
```

Check this demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/RhvqyS5aQAYpRDIPAvLE?p=preview